# How to install the 4.4 kernel on a unbootable system

Tags: boot, kernel, uefi

My laptop does not boot Freya.So I think that I should upgrade my kernel to 4.4.But the system is unbootable and gives a error and does not show the GUI.

But how could I do this when it doesn't boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can boot into a Flash Drive with elementary OS and chroot into your machine.

First get root with `sudo su`, and create some directory using `mkdir /mnt/mainOS`.

Then just mount your HDD with the `mount /dev/<your id> /mnt/mainOS` command and `chroot /mnt/mainOS /bin/bash -i` into it. Your bash will now behave like you would be in your normal machine. Upgrade the kernel as usual, !`exit`! and `reboot` should then do the rest. ;)

***Tips***: You can detect your drives with `df -h`.

*You can find more in-depth information about chroot here: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/chroot/*

Comment: For some reason it is booting now.Anyways I think that this will be useful later